# Export to PDF with String and Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

I need to export excel sheet as PDF named with String and Cell Value for Example XXXY - Cell Value
Note: i do not need codes that uses path location for the saving file
I tried the following code

```
Sub IVI_Formatting_Export_Two_PDF ()

Dim strFilename As String

Dim srn As String Dim SWPDF As Worksheet

Set SWPDF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets ("BSS CPES MainPage")

srn = "CPE Main-Page"

strFilename = SWPDF.Range ("F7").Value

Create File name with Warehouse Name

Export2PDF

SWPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat

Type:=xlTypePDF,

Filename:=strFilename & srn,

Quality:=xl QualityStandard,

IncludeDocProperties:=False,

IgnorePrintAreas:=False,

From:=1,

To:=1,

OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Post codes as text not as picture. What problem are you facing? Yellow highlighted line problem is double quote. try `SWPDF.Range("F7").Value`.

Comment: Code is added instead of picture. The problem that I can not export the excel sheet as a PDF with the specific name (Cell Value of F7 - XXXX ) where XXXX is string

Comment: Check my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify a path to export PDF. Without path where it will be saved? You can use variable to specify path. Currently I have used same as file path. Your problem was in filename parameter. Try below sub.

```
Sub IVI_Formatting_Export_Two_PDF()
Dim strFilename As String
Dim srn As String
Dim SWPDF As Worksheet

Set SWPDF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BSS CPES MainPage")

srn = "CPE Main-Page"
strFilename = SWPDF.Range("F7").Value

'Create File name with Warehouse Name
'Export2PDF

    SWPDF.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & "_" & srn & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

'Clear memory
Set SWPDF = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here `Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename & "_" & srn & ".pdf"` will export the PDF to same folder where your workbook is located. Also you must include `.pdf` extension to export excel sheet as pdf.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh :) , yeah it worked fine with me, 2nd i searched for this command and all commands were specificed with specific path which is not desirable , so another codes worked with me without specifice the path but couldn't insert cell value so i thought it would be the same